# Python static inheritance in class variable

Tags: python, oop, static

In python, is there a way to get the class name in the "static constructor"? I would like to initialize a class variable using an inherited class method.

```
class A():
    @classmethod
    def _getInit(cls):
        return 'Hello ' + cls.__name__

class B(A):
    staticField = B._getInit()
```

> NameError: name 'B' is not defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name `B` is not assigned to until the full `class` suite has been executed and a class object has been created. For the same reason, the `__name__` attribute on the class is not set until the class object is created either.

You'd have to assign that attribute afterwards:

```
class A():
    @classmethod
    def _getInit(cls):
        return 'Hello ' + cls.__name__

class B(A):
    pass

B.staticField = B._getInit()
```

The alternative is to use a class decorator (which is passed the newly-created class object) or use a metaclass (which creates the class object in the first place and is given the name to use).